# C++ Cypher issue

Tags: c++, encryption

I am new to the world of coding and been experimenting on making a cypher with c++ but it is throwing an error and I don't know how to fix it. Help would be appreciated, Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>                                               
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(){

/* Variables Declaration! */


string alphabets{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};   

string key{"XWZYLMNOPQRSTUVABCDEFGHIJKuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrst"};

string input{};

string encrypted_message{};

string decrypted_message{};

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

cout << "Welcome To the Cypher!" << endl;
cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;



cout << "Enter the code: " << endl;
getline(cin,input);


/*Encryption Part Code*/ 

cout << "Encrypting!"<< endl;
cout << endl ;

for (char c:input) {

    size_t postition = alphabets.find(c);
    if (postition != string::npos){
        encrypted_message += key.at(postition);
    }
    else 
        encrypted_message += c;
}   
cout << endl ;
cout << encrypted_message << endl;


/* Decryption Part Code */

cout << "Decrypting!" << endl;
cout << endl ;

for (char c : encrypted_message) {

    size_t position = key.find(c);

    if (position != string::npos){
        decrypted_message += alphabets.at(c);
    } 

    else
        decrypted_message += c;

}   
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    



cout << endl;
cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" ;
cout << endl ;

return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting -

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 88) >= this->size() (which is
>   52)

Comment: Is this Caeser cypher?  What is the error?

Comment: It's not a Caeser cypher.

Comment: What is the theory and what is the error message?

Comment: This program takes your text as input, iterates through each letter compares it with the letter in the alphabets variable and if it matches it returns the position where it is at and then it takes that position and takes out the character at that position from key variable and then puts it in the encryted_message variable this process repeats till your input has completely encrypted then it decrypts the encrypted_message with the same process by which we converted it.

Comment: error message : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 88) >= this->size() (which is 52)

Comment: @rippedguy You should include this error in the question so it's clear to everyone :)

Comment: @AndreasDM Thanks for the advice, I am new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printing the backtrace of the process dump using gdb,

```
    (gdb) bt
    #0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
    #1  0x00007ffff7aed535 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
    #2  0x00007ffff7eb5943 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #3  0x00007ffff7ebb8a6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #4  0x00007ffff7ebb8e1 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #5  0x00007ffff7ebbb14 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #6  0x00007ffff7eb7851 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #7  0x00007ffff7f4779f in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::at(unsigned long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #8  0x000055555555559b in main () at cypher.cc:61
```

According to #8, there was a problem at line 61.

```
decrypted_message += alphabets.at(c);
```

According to #7, there was a problem when you attempted "at" function.

Your error reads,

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at: __n (which is 88) >= this->size() (which is 52)

That means you are trying to access at n (88) which exceeds the size of alphabets (52).

> What you need to do is change "c" to "position".

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is caused by the line

```
decrypted_message += alphabets.at(c);
```

You index with a character, and so if the first character in the `encrypted_message` is `X` (equal to 88 in ascii), it tries to access element at index 88 which is off bounds. The `.at()` then throws an exception.

---

Your intention was to use the `position`

```
if (position != string::npos){
    // decrypted_message += alphabets.at(c);
    decrypted_message += alphabets.at(position);
}
```

Stepping over the code with a debugger makes it easier to find these bugs.